# Many to Many Self Association Sequelize

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

**EDIT:**

I got a little progress... I changed the relation to:

```
 Survivor.associate = (models) => {
    Survivor.belongsToMany(models.Survivor, { through: models.InfectedsReports, as: 'Reporter', foreignKey: 'ReportedId' })
    Survivor.belongsToMany(models.Survivor, { through: models.InfectedsReports, as: 'Reported', foreignKey: 'ReporterId' })
  }
```

and now it shows both fields correctly, but in the insertion the values comes null!!!

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have the followings tables:

Survivors:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Survivors', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
      name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      gender: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.ENUM,
        values: ['M', 'F']
      },
      isInfected: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: 0
      },
      latitude: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: null
     },
     longitude: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: null
     },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
      },
    })
  },

  down: (queryInterface) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Survivors');
  }

};
```

Infecteds reported by other survivals:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('InfectedsReports', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
      ReporterId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Survivors',
          key: 'id',
        }
      },
      ReportedId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Survivors',
          key: 'id',
        }
      },
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('SurvivorsItems');
  }
};
```

And the models:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Survivor = sequelize.define('Survivor', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    gender: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['M', 'F']
    },
    isInfected: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    latitude: DataTypes.STRING,
    longitude: DataTypes.STRING,
  });
  Survivor.associate = (models) => {
    Survivor.belongsToMany(models.Survivor, { through: 'InfectedsReports', as: 'Reporter', foreignKey: 'id' })
    Survivor.belongsToMany(models.Survivor, { through: 'InfectedsReports', as: 'Reported', foreignKey: 'id' })
  }
  return Survivor;

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const InfectedsReports = sequelize.define('InfectedsReports',{
    ReporterId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    ReportedId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
  });
  return InfectedsReports;
}
```

I am not having success on inserting because the many to many self association:

> Executing (default): INSERT INTO `InfectedsReports` (`id`) VALUES
>   (DEFAULT); Unhandled rejection SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError:
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`zombieresistance`.`InfectedsReports`, CONSTRAINT
>   `InfectedsReports_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ReporterId`) REFERENCES
>   `Survivors` (`id`))

if I remove one belongsToMany declaration one fild appears, but not the other, and the id in the insertion appears to be null:

controller:

```
module.exports = {

  async create(req, res) {
    const { id, idReported } = req.params;

    try {

      const reporter = await Survivor.findByPk(id)
      const reported = await Survivor.findByPk(idReported)
      if (null === reported || null === reporter) {
        res.status(404).send('Survivor not found')
      }

      const report = InfectedsReports.create({ idReporter: id, idReported: idReported })
      res.send(report)

    } catch (e) {

      console.log(e)
      res.status(500).send(e)

    }
  },

}
```

Can someone help me to understand how do i create the self association in this problem?

tks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED:**

this alteration is the checkmate!!!

```
Survivor.associate = (models) => {
    Survivor.belongsToMany(models.Survivor, { through: models.InfectedsReports, as: 'Reporter', foreignKey: 'ReportedId' })
    Survivor.belongsToMany(models.Survivor, { through: models.InfectedsReports, as: 'Reported', foreignKey: 'ReporterId' })
}
```

Thankyou!